# Generating multiple responses from AWS API Gateway

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've been fiddling around with API Gateway with DynamoDB. The below map template allows me to generate a single JSON response from AWS API Gateway.

```
{
    "TableName": "NPddb"
    "PrimaryKey": "id",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "id = :v1",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {
            "S": "$input.params('id')"
        }
    }
}
```

which will result in a nice JSON being published at a specified "id".

This is all well and nice, but how do I return say two items or even the entire table? Does this come under a lambda call?

Comment: You should refer the dynamodb api documentation for Query and Scan http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was the create a Global Secondary Index in the DynamoDB table and query that. In this case, I'm querying GSI "atype-index" for the string "atype".

```
{
    "TableName": "NPddb",
    "IndexName": "atype-index",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "atype = :v1",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {
            "S": "$input.params('atype')"
        }
    }
}
```